# compiling a simple application using boost process generate error

Tags: c++, boost, process

I am using Boost 1.64 and generated a project in VS 2013 using CMake. The code is as follow:

```
#include <boost\process.hpp>
namespace bp = boost::process;
int main()
{
    int result = bp::system("g++ main.cpp");
}
```

when I try to call it, I am getting this error:

```
Error   1   error C3646: 'noexcept' : unknown override specifier    C:\Local\boost\boost\process\detail\config.hpp
```

do I neeed to add any other header file to be able to compile the code?

Note: I know that probably the code doesn't run, as on windows I don't have gcc, but this is not my problem, I just copy sample code form boost document to make sure I did not change any art of it.

## Edit 1

I change the code to this:

```
#define BOOST_NO_CXX11_NOEXCEPT
#include <boost\process.hpp>
namespace bp = boost::process;
int main()
{
      int result = bp::system("g++ main.cpp");
}
```

But I am still getting the same error. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: You still need to include `<boost/config.hpp>`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `noexcept` is not supported by VS 2013.
You need to define `BOOST_NO_CXX11_NOEXCEPT` and then include `<boost/config.hpp>`, as documented [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/config/doc/html/boost_config/boost_macro_reference.html#boost_config.boost_macro_reference.macros_that_describe_c__11_features_not_supported).

> `BOOST_NO_CXX11_NOEXCEPT`: The compiler does not support `noexcept`.