# Boost Process errors on vs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, boost

I'm trying to use Boost 1.66 with VS2010, and I'm having some issues on compile after I include the  header. Anyone had similar issues and can help me to fix this?

I need to call a ffmpeg process, and using windows CreateProcess was a pain in the a** to build it and didnt worked.

```
Error   1   error C3646: 'noexcept' : unknown override specifier    C:\_libs\boost_1_66_0\boost\process\detail\config.hpp   65
Error   2   error C2660: 'boost::process::process_error::process_error' : function does not take 2 arguments    C:\_libs\boost_1_66_0\boost\process\detail\config.hpp   72
Error   3   error C2660: 'boost::process::process_error::process_error' : function does not take 2 arguments    C:\_libs\boost_1_66_0\boost\process\detail\config.hpp   77
Error   4   error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'std::error_code' to 'boost::process::process_error' C:\_libs\boost_1_66_0\boost\process\detail\config.hpp   82
Error   5   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Char'    C:\_libs\boost_1_66_0\boost\process\detail\config.hpp   86
Error   6   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\_libs\boost_1_66_0\boost\process\detail\config.hpp   86
Error   7   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'null_char'   C:\_libs\boost_1_66_0\boost\process\detail\config.hpp   86
Error   8   error C2144: syntax error : 'char' should be preceded by ';'    C:\_libs\boost_1_66_0\boost\process\detail\config.hpp   87
Error   9   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\_libs\boost_1_66_0\boost\process\detail\config.hpp   87
Error   10  error C2086: 'int boost::process::detail::constexpr' : redefinition C:\_libs\boost_1_66_0\boost\process\detail\config.hpp   87
```

Comment: did you follow the instructions here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629421/how-to-use-boost-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: I'm using pre built binaries. So that step isnt required.

Comment: From what I can tell those errors pertain to C++11 and later features that are used in your installed boost version. Obviously MSVC 2010 didn't have full support for C++11, and has no support for C++14 and now C++17. It doesn't speak the language you are trying to feed it.

Comment: Can you try an older version of Boost?

Comment: Older versions < 1.64 doesnt have the process header.

Comment: Then upgrade visual studio.

Comment: Also, I saw the same issue with people using Vs2013.  There's this solution for the noexcept thing, but vs2010 is apparently ignoring it...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689764/compiling-a-simple-application-using-boost-process-generate-error

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2013 doesn't support noxcept, constexpr.

Try an older boost or add before including boost

```
#define noexcept
#define constexpr
```